# A reference for patch topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I saw  a paper that  defines  the definition of *patch* topology on the *Spectrume* of a commutative ring with identity. Is there any reference for this concept that give some property for this topology? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

See [Prime ideal structure in commutative rings](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-142-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251026-X/), by *Hochster*.